# Show current user name in the "recent names" section of the profile

Tags: feature-request, profile-page, display-names, recent

It is a minor request. Not many people change their names, so they might not notice this. I probably won't be changing my name either(just once or maybe twice `:P` ) much.

[image: Image 1]

In the screenshot above, the **recent names** section(if available to you) is clickable and shows a modal with the past names I used.

[image: Image 2]

As you can notice, the modal isn't displaying the name I currently have in use(*Dream Eater*) and I'd like to get that name listed too as I can then have knowledge of when can I next update my name. `:P`

I can currently access this value by trying to change my name which'll display a red-popup with the relevant information. But it's just too troublesome, and I'd like to be spoon-fed.

Comment: 1. Why is the second name in that screenshot messed up? 2. Why are you JPG compressing screenshots?! :O

Comment: @Doorknob 1. I was using that nickname for fun. Didn't know that it'd stick with me for a month. `:|` Being still new to SO and all :P Hence, I edited the image to create explosion effect. 2. Would it matter if I provide you with PNG?

Comment: 1. Oh that makes sense. 2. No, just my image-quality-alarm going off :)

Comment: I think I changed my name from DHorse1 to DHorse to match my SO account on the day I created my account.  That might be excluded but doesn't show so I'm not even sure.

Comment: Oh... You can click the digit (1) and it shows.  My mistake. It started off as User99999